# How to write a number of large files with memory efficiency in Java 7

Tags: java, java-io, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I have a requirement to write a huge data (I can get data up to 1KB in one second) to a number of different files (each file can raise up to few GiBs of space.

In my application, one thread constantly produces the data and currently I am creating one thread per file to write the data (creating a new file depends on certain criteria on the input data that the producer is producing).

I am using FileWriter wrapped by a BufferedWriter. Initially I tried writing with the default buffered size of 8KB. But since that makes the number of writes per second higher, the CPU consumption increases rapidly without coming down.

So, I have now increased the buffered size to 50KB.
But this is making my application crash due to outOfMemory problem.

When I profiled it, I could see that all the data is being stored in the form of char arrays which is created by the buffered writer (remember one buffered writer per file. And I have around 400 files like that).

Please suggest how to overcome the problem here.
I would also like to know if there are any alternatives or better ways to implement the requirement.

I cannot decrease the buffer size to less than 50KB as this is make my CPU go up to 100%.

Edit: Okay, I thought I need not add code as I could make the requirement very clear (and moreover I have nothing to do with the code. It was alright, just that I was looking for efficiency). But since, my question was downvoted, I am including my code here.

```
public class DataWriter {

      private LinkedBlockingQueue<MyDataObject> dataQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
      private ExecutorService singleThread = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
      private boolean isRunning = true;
      private Map<String, FileWriterThread> map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, FileWriterThread>());

      public DataWriter() {
         singleThread.submit(new DataProcessor());
      }

      public void writeProducedData(MyDataObject object) {
          if (isRunning) {
             dataQueue.offer(object);
          }
      }

      public void stopWriting() {
          isRunning = false;
      }

      private class DataProcessor implements Runnable {

         @Override
         public void run() {
            while (isRunning) {

            MyDataObject obj = dataQueue.take();

            if (obj.getMapKey() == null) {
                FileWriterThread thread = new FileWriterThread();
                map.put(obj.getMapKey(), thread);
            }

            FileWriterThread thread = map.get(obj.getMapKey());
            thread.writeData(obj);
         }
        }        
      }
    }
```

FileWriterThread class:

```
public class FileWriterThread {

       private ExecutorService singleThread = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
       private FileWriter fileWriter;
       private BufferedWriter bufferedWriter;
       private LinkedBlockingQueue<MyDataObject> dataQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    public FileWriterThread() {
      singleThread.submit(new DataProcessor());
    }

    public void writeData(MyDataObject obj) {
     if (fileWriter == null) {
       createWriter(obj.getFileName());
     }
     dataQueue.offer(obj);
    }

    public void stopWriting() {
      // close the file writer and buffer writer gracefully
    }

    private void createWriter(String fileName) {
      try {
        fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName, true);
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter, 50);
      } catch (Exception e){}   
    }

    private class DataProcessor implements Runnable {

       @Override
       public void run() {
         MyDataObject obj =  dataQueue.take();
         try {
           bufferedWriter.write(obj.toString());
         } catch(Exception e) {}
       }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Show the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: If you're writing files on a single disk, using a single thread to write will most probably be faster, and consume much less memory than haveig 400 threads (which is huge) created on the fly and each writing to a separate file. Of course, we can only make guesses since you didn't post any single line of code.

Comment: Are you writing each file at 1MB/s? Because that would be 400 MB/s and not possible on a HDD. What is your hardware platform?

Comment: Sorry @AndrewHeys, corrected it to 1 KB/s

Comment: @JBNizet, please see the code I have added. Also, If I use just a single thread to write to 400 files, the volume of data that I am writing is still the same right. Can you please let me know how the memory is going to be decreased here?

Comment: A thread, not doing anything, already consumes 1 MB of memory. So, if you go from 400 threads to 1, you gain 399MB. Now, if you have 400 threads all writing to a buffer of 50KB, that makes 20 MB. 1 thread doing the same thing sequentially on all files just needs one buffer, so that means 19.5 MB less memory. Then, if the data taken from the queue(s) in memory are written to the disk faster, it means less objects stay in the queue consuming memory.

Comment: @JBNizet, do you say that we can use one bufferedwriter can be used to write to multiple files? Can you please explain how? I thought this is not possible. Also, you say that '' a thread, not doing anything, already consumes 1 MB of memory ''.  Can you please explain how? Does Java allocate 1MB to each newly created thread?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that. I'm saying thet one thread, writing to N files sequentially, will only need one reader opened at any given time. Yes, 1MB is allocated for each thread, which needs its own stack for local variables and method calls.

Answer (score 0):

Having all these threads buys you nothing -- the whole thing is IO-bound, not CPU-bound (or would be, if your CPU wasn't struggling to juggle 400 threads).

In a single thread, just have your producer write to the appropriate writer:

```
   Map<String, Writer> writers = ...;

   private handleOutput(byte[] output, String key) {
        writers.get(key).write(output);
   }
```

If you want to separate your concerns, maybe having *a few* (not hundreds) threads for writing and one for producing, separate them with a `Queue`.

Comment: Thanks for the response @slim. One question here. If I use a single thread to write to multiple files, am I going to get any additional benefit than decreasing the number of active threads? I believe that the memory occupied would be same as we are going to create the same number of objects may it be on separate threads or on the same thread right?

Comment: If your machine isn't churning threads so much, it should write to the files faster, draining the buffers sooner. To save memory, you could make the buffers smaller. To use bigger buffers, you could increase the heap size (Java `-Xmx` command line params).